# Delete db row from page without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, refresh

I have a script that deletes a row from my DB, it works well, but the problem is that I have to refresh the page to see the changes, on the client side I have one table with all the rows showed, how do I delete the tr,td's dynamically from page without this refresh? I hope that js code will be enough.

JS:

```
$(".delete_button").click(function () {
    var delete_id = $(this).attr('name');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'delete.php',
        data: {
            'variable': delete_id
        },
        success: function (html) {
            alert(delete_id);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: look at your developer console

Comment: @RTX You need to parse your HTML and remove appropriate node manually by javascript. Show us your HTML.

Comment: @RTX please do select the answer that helped in your case to fix the problem so that others facing the same problem can also get the benefit.

Comment: Hello, can you mark the answer as correct that worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this

1. You should track the row of the record you are deleting, lets say with the `delete_id` we will do like below

   `<tr id="delete_id"><td><a href="#">Delete Link</a></td></tr>`

   and then in your click function

   ```
   $ ( ".delete_button" ).click ( function () {
       var delete_id = $ ( this ).attr ( 'name' );
       $.ajax ( {
           type : "POST",
           url : 'delete.php',
           data : { 'variable' : delete_id },
           success : function ( html ) {
               $ ( "#" + delete_id ).remove ()
           } } );
   } );
   ```
2. Without tracking it depending on the html structure

   `<tr id="delete_id"><td><a href="#">Delete Link</a></td></tr>`

   JS

   ```
   $ ( ".delete_button" ).click ( function () {
       var delete_id = $ ( this ).attr ( 'name' );
       var anchorLink = $ ( this );
       $.ajax ( {
           type : "POST",
           url : 'delete.php',
           data : { 'variable' : delete_id },
           success : function ( html ) {
               anchorLink.parent ().prent ().remove ();
           } } );
   } );
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the row in your `success` handler. Something like this.

```
$(".delete_button").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var delete_id = $(this).attr('name');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'delete.php',
        data:{'variable': delete_id},
        success:function(html) {
        alert(delete_id);
        //now remove the row
        $this.parent('tr').remove();
        }
    });
});
```